# Does a Cron job overwrite itself

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I can't seem to get my script to run in parallel every minute via cron on Ubuntu 14.

I have created a cron job which executes every minute. The cron job executes a script that runs much longer than a minute. When a minute expires it seems the new cron execution overwrites the previous execution. Is this correct? Any ideas welcomed.

I need concurrent independent running jobs. The cron job runs a script which queries a mysql database. The idea is to poll a db- if yes execute script in its own process.

Comment: Check [Prevent duplicate cron jobs running](http://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running)

Comment: One has to ask why you're trying to run a job every minute that takes longer than a minute to complete.

Comment: Do you *want* successive executions to overlap or not? That's not clear from your question. Is "I **can** seem ..." supposed to be "I **can't** seem ..."?

Comment: If you **want** multiple concurrent instances, but can only get one instance to run at a time, you'll need to show a reproducer for that case -- since default out-of-the-box behavior with Vixie cron is to run new instances even if old ones are still active, what's going on is necessarily specific to your configuration and/or the script you're running (unless you're using a non-Vixie implementation of cron).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a locking mechanism to identify that the script is already running.

There are several ways of doing this but you need to be careful to use an atomic method.

I use lock directories as creating a directory is guaranteed to be atomic -

```
LOCKDIR=/tmp/myproc.lock

if ! mkdir $LOCKDIR >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  print -u2 "Processing already running - terminating"
  exit 1
fi

trap "rm -rf $LOCKDIR" EXIT
```

Comment: I would recommend using [`lockfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile) if you have the option.  If the host crashes while the lock directory exists, no future instances of the job will run until the directory is manually removed.

Comment: `lockfile` is a fine tool if one needs to care about portability, but if only targeting modern Linux I'd tend to suggest `flock` instead.

Comment: If I put a locking mechanism in will it stop the next cron execution? I want the first to continue and the second to start in parallel.

Comment: @Sascha, that's what Vixie `cron` already does out-of-the-box, so if that's the behavior you want, you don't need to change anything at all. (Some other implementations, such as `fcron`, give you explicit control of that behavior in your crontab).

Comment: @Sascha, ...and that's why all the answers here are assuming that you want only one at a time -- the behavior you're asking for is what's already there by default!

Comment: I understand that cron allows parallel execution. However, What I need is one of my jobs to run in parallel. e.g. cron job 1 starts a script which runs for 45 minutes. cron job 1 is set to  run every minute. I want a new instance of the same job running every 45 minutes. Every instance should be allowed to finish.

Comment: @Charles, I am trying get parallel execution of the same job not running one job after another

Comment: @Sascha, I'm annoyed at having to repeat myself. **Default behavior already is what you say you want.** If you're getting anything different, that's a property of the command you're running, not a property of `cron` itself.

Answer (score 2):

cron will not stop a previous execution of a process to start a new one.  cron will simply kick off the new process even though the old process is still running.

If you need cron to terminate the previous process, you'll need to modify your script to handle that itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common occurrence. Try adding a check in your script to see if a lockfile already exists. If it does, exit. If not, continue.

Cronjobs are not overrun. They do however have the possibility of overlapping. Unless your script explicitly kills any pre-existing process, it shouldn't be able to stop the previously running script.

However, introducing the concept of lockfiles will save you from all these confusions altogether.

Comment: The OP is asking how to cause their cron job to run multiple concurrent instances, not how to ensure that only one runs. (This isn't clear from the question, but they've made it explicit in comments on another answer).